# TransactionalLog Backup Job failed

Tags: sql-server, backup

We have a three jobs scheduled on production server. Full backup, Differential backup and Transaction Log backup. The first two backup successfully, but the Transaction Log backup is failing. It shows below error.

> Date      1/23/2019 4:00:00 AM
>
> Log       Job History (JOB_NAME)
>
> Step ID       1
>
> Server        SERVER_NAME
>
> Job Name      (JOB_NAME)
>
> Step Name     1
>
> Duration      00:00:01
>
> Sql Severity  16
>
> Sql Message ID    3013
>
> Operator Emailed
>
> Operator Net sent
>
> Operator Paged
>
> Retries Attempted 0
>
> Message
>
> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER_2016. Cannot open
>   backup device 'BACKUP_PATH\database_Trans_4.trn'. Operating system
>   error 32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used
>   by another process.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201)  BACKUP LOG is
>   terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step
>   failed.

I have edited the message to hide the server details for security reasons.

The Backup script used is

```
Declare @number nchar(2)
set @number=isnull((select max(ID) from database.dbo.Backup_Transactionlog),0)+1

declare @path1 varchar(max)
set @path1=N'E:\DB_Backup\database_TransactionalLog_Backup\database_Trans_' + ltrim(rtrim(@number)) +'.trn'

BACKUP LOG [database]
TO  DISK = @path1
WITH INIT

insert into database.dbo.Backup_Transactionlog 
values (@path1,getdate())
```

After doing lots of research i found a solution. I changed the WITH INIT Option of the backup syntax with WITH FORMAT. But still the backup is failing.

Could any one please provide any solution that would make my day.

Thanks.!!

Comment: Try to change backup file name with smth else, for example 'tran" + select replace(replace(convert(char(19), getdate(), 120), ':', '_'), ' ','_')

Comment: There is one strange thing that is happening. This is scheduled backup so the backup is taken every 1 hr. But one of the backup is successful. for eg. if the backup is taken in the following sequence  

1ST BACKUP AT 12 AM FAILED;
2ND BACKUP AT 1 AM FAILED;
3RD BACKUP AT 2 AM FAILED;
4TH BACKUP AT 3 AM FAILED;
5TH BACKUP AT 4 AM SUCCESS

How can this happen?

Comment: @karanT probably since the 5th backup is not being used by a process, or it is a new .trn file. The processes that could be using it are restores, other backups to that file, antivirus scans , ... . Do you need to backup to the same files? I would advise looking into ola hallengren's backup solution.

Comment: @RandiVertongen every time a new backup .trn files is created. It will overwrite the previous .trn files in the folder. How do I come to know, which process is blocking the backup?

Comment: @Karan.T. If it is being used by T-SQL (restore) commands, you could execute the query: select * from sys.dm_exec_requests cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) on the server('s). For other processes, see this link: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: I have to ask, why are you overwriting tlogs? Also, why log the execution? It's logged by default in  msdb.dbo.backupset (and subsequent tables).